# Menu in absolute position in now showed in full width

Tags: css

I have a header which is 1090px wide and position is relative. Menu div position is absolute. This menu is not shown in full width (look at screenshot, white background is size of menu).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<a href="/"><img class="logo" src="/kubilai/templates/frontend//images/logo.png"></a>
<div class="header">
<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
<ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-101 first"><a href="/kubilai/index.php/home"><span>Home</span></a></li><li class="item-104 current active"><a href="/kubilai/"><span>Pradinis</span></a></li><li class="item-105"><a href="/kubilai/index.php/uzsakymas"><span>uzsakymas</span></a></li><li class="item-106"><a href="/kubilai/"><span>darbu galerija</span></a></li><li class="item-107 last"><a href="/kubilai/"><span>kontaktai</span></a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    width: 1090px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.header
{
    height: 104px;
    margin-top: 36px;
    /*+box-shadow:0 7px 6px #F1F0F0;*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 6px #F1F0F0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 6px #F1F0F0;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 7px 6px #F1F0F0;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 6px #F1F0F0;
}
.header .menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 0;
}
.header .menu LI
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.header .menu LI A
{
    color: #B5B5B5;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: calibri;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: a preview on [link](http://jsfiddle.net/) will realy help

Comment: give some width to .menu `width:700px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Solution**

All you need to do is remove `menu` class from `ul`

Change this

```
<ul class="nav menu">
```

to this

```
<ul class="nav">
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/v7HMj/show)**

Comment: wow, i had no idea extra class would influence on this. thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `width:100%` to absolute elements

```
.header .menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 0;
    width:100%
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AYuwuSa/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

@Sowmya's answer works, but as an alternative I personally prefer setting explicit positioning properties when using absolute *positioning*:

```
.header .menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AYuwuSa/4)**

Answer (score 0):

I think following code will work.

```
.header .menu{
   position: absolute;
   top: 16px;
   right: 0;
   width:100%
}
```